# IOS: viewcontroller transition

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller

In my app I want open a UIViewController but with a zoom transition; 
I have an image and when I touch it, it should enalarge itself and go fullscreen.
Should I use a UIViewController or a simple UIView?

Comment: you want to open a viewcontroller, but you are talking about a imageview. Which one do you need to open?

Comment: I have 4 imageview inside a view, and when I touch one of them I want that this image expand itself in fullscreen ok? It's simply and I do it with an animation; my problem is that when I open this image I want to have another viewcontroller to do another things... then I'm asking if is better to use a view controller or simply a subview

Comment: UIView is enough. You can create an another UIView in IB and set property. Add a imageView as a subview of that view and when the user touch the imageview which is in self.view, pass that image to the imageview which you have created in the anotherview and add that view as a subview of self.view.